# How to update array variable of one object inside array of that object type using setState function

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to update subject's array inside list of departments for one particular department. Here is the code for clear information:

```
const addSubjectToDepartment = (id) => {
    var updatedDepartments = departments.map((obj, index) => {
      if(index == id) {
        return {
          ...obj,
          subjects: obj.subjects.push(subject)
        }
      }
      return obj;
    })

    setDepartments(updatedDepartments);
}
```

The **id** parameter will be the index of department for which subject needs to be added.
I am trying to map through departments array and then add subject for matching index. I observed when I hover on subjects it shows never[] type.

I am trying to display those subjects of a department using below code

```
{     
    departments[departmentSubjectsDiv.index]
    .subjects.map((obj, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{obj.sname}</td>
                <td>{obj.scode}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
}
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Subject"
        onChange={onDeptSubjectInputChange}
    />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="scode" placeholder="Code"
        onChange={onDeptSubjectInputChange}
    />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="button" value="Add" 
        onClick={() => {
            addSubjectToDepartment(departmentSubjectsDiv.index);
        }}
    />
</td>
```

So when I try to click on **Add** button after entering values it does not render the page and in console I can see the error
**Uncaught TypeError: departments[departmentSubjectsDiv.index].subjects.map is not a function**

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example via the likes of [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after observing and playing with the code, I found the solution.

Here is the link to reproducible example to get more insight about the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-element-to-array-in-an-list-of-objects-using-usestate-6xw145?file=/src/App.js

Initially I was trying to push the subject using push method of array which was returning object not array. So I just modified it as shown below to make it return array instead of object and it solved my problem:

```
var updatedDepartments = departments.map((obj, index) => {
    if(index == id) {
        return {
          ...obj,
          subjects: obj.subjects.length === 0 ? [subject] : [...obj.subjects, subject]
        }
    }
    return obj;
})
```